# How do you handle errors when rotating vector data in 2D?

Tags: statistics, vectors, vector-analysis, rotations, error-propagation

I have a vector data set in component-form in two columns with error (x-component and y-component: $x+\delta x$ and $y+\delta y$). I need to rotate this data by an angle $\theta$ to a new coordinate system $x'$ and $y'$.

To do this with perfect data, I understand that you can use the 2D rotation matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x' \\ y'  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos (\theta) & -\sin(\theta)\\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}.$$

However, for imprecise data where I have columns for $\delta x$ and $\delta y$, how can I handle this error?

Is it as simple as:

$$\begin{bmatrix}\delta x' \\ \delta y'  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos (\theta) & -\sin(\theta)\\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\delta x \\ \delta y \end{bmatrix}$$
or something more complicated?

Comment: Rotations are linear, so the formula for the error term is exactly what you have written down, as simple as that.

Comment: Are your $\delta x$ and $\delta y$ random variables? (For example, are you asking this in the context of a scientific experiment or a data science project?) If $\delta x$ and $\delta y$ are independent normally-distributed random variables with equal variance, then $\delta x '$ and $\delta y'$ will also be independent normally-distributed random variables with the same variance.